# How does cpprestsdk use MARCO to define constants

Tags: c++, cpprest-sdk

For example in `include/cpprest/http_msg.h` the `header_names` is defined as:

```
class header_names
{
public:
#define _HEADER_NAMES
#define DAT(a, b) _ASYNCRTIMP const static utility::string_t a;
#include "cpprest/details/http_constants.dat"
#undef _HEADER_NAMES
#undef DAT
};
```

and in `cpprest/details/http_constants.dat` there's would be a section like this:

```
#ifdef _HEADER_NAMES
DAT(accept,                 "Accept")
DAT(accept_charset,         "Accept-Charset")
...
#endif
```

from the `DAT(a, b)` definition, the variable `b` is not used.

However when we do a simple assignment:

```
auto a = header_names::accept;
```

the variable `a` contains the string `"Accept"`.

I'm not sure how could this happen.

I use `godbolt.org` with option `-E` to get pre-processor of the following code

```
class header_names
{
public:
#define DAT(a, b) _ASYNCRTIMP const static utility::string_t a;
DAT(accept,                 "Accept")
DAT(accept_charset,         "Accept-Charset")
#undef DAT
};
```

and the generated result is

```
class header_names
{

_ASYNCRTIMP const static utility::string_t accept;
_ASYNCRTIMP const static utility::string_t accept_charset;

};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The header file contains the class declaration of the static variables. The corresponding definitions, including the initializations, are in [`release/src/http/common/http_msg.cpp`](https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk/blob/master/Release/src/http/common/http_msg.cpp#L1160).

```
#define _HEADER_NAMES
#define DAT(a, b) const utility::string_t header_names::a = _XPLATSTR(b);
#include "cpprest/details/http_constants.dat"
#undef _HEADER_NAMES
#undef DAT
```

Comment: The hint to this activity is the explicit #undef in the original header. that is clearly no accident, and strongly suggests that macro takes on new life somewhere else.

Comment: @WhozCraig Right, with the other clue being the second argument, which *had* to be used somewhere else. First thought was to run a search for `constants.dat` which returned a couple dozen hits, split between headers and implementation files. Next search was for `_HEADER_NAMES` which narrowed it down to to the linked code.